# Can I avoid locking a bool if it only goes from false to true once?

Tags: c++, boolean, atomic

I have a `bool` that is being accessed by multiple threads, but that value can only transition from `false` to `true`, once, during the runtime of a program.  So long as the value is *eventually* `true`, I don't care of each thread has an immediately consistent view of the variable--as long as they all eventually pick it up.

Unfortunately, checking the value of this value is called pretty frequently, so locking around the value is expensive.

I've seen other posts where people have talked about the cache may not be refreshed correctly, but what are the **exact** side effects of not locking on reads?

Thanks!

Comment: To be pedantic the program may never see the bool change state.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes but `volatile` has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: `volatile` is not enough for thread synchronization.

Comment: You'll get away with it.  If not from a processor with a strong memory model then from the memory barriers that the OS needs to get its job done.  But you do have to tell the compiler that the value can change from code other than yours or will not have a good reason to reload the value from memory.  Test it, don't tell anybody at SO about it.

Comment: From what I understand, `volatile` will just prevent the value from being optimized out, which can cause incorrect behavior otherwise.  Based on @LWimsey's response below, it sounds like `std::atomic_bool` might actually already implement lockless bools in this case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No! http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/

Comment: Using `volatile` for the boolean in all threads that access it is enough to guaranty the compiler won't put the boolean in a register. [Cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) will guarantee that all threads and/or cores and/or processors see any updates. All read / write operations to volatiles will be in order, but the compiler and / or processor may reorder read / write operations if they are a mix of non-volatile and volatile, which wouldn't be thread safe.

Comment: Using `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient for concurrent access to a shared variable. There are portable, standard alternatives with none of the drawbacks of `volatile`. It has **no place** here. None. http://cxx.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact side effect is undefined behavior.
With a regular `bool`, the compiler is not aware that it will be accessed in multiple threads and therefore it may apply optimizations that lead to undefined behavior (such as an update not visible to other threads).

Replace `bool` with `std::atomic<bool>`, use it exactly like you would have used `bool` and you are fine. No locking necessary.

Comment: The documentation for `std::atomic` suggests that being lockless is not guaranteed (the `is_lock_free` function).  Is there a compiler specific list of types that are lock free?

Comment: @Redmumba check the `ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE` macro, and similar ones for other built-in types (or in C++17 use the constexpr `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` constant).

Answer (score 0):

Use atomic, instead. It is cheaper than any locks and will solve your problem with consistency.

Another way: do not check your variable many times. Notify every thread of a variable change.